# How to handle required fields in display:"none"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `display:none` element, that contains `required` inputs. When I submit form it must focus on required fields, but as they are not displayed Im not able to do it. What I want is to make this element `display:block` and then focus on the input when there validation error ocured.

This is how my code looks like:

```
<form>

<div style="display: none">
    <input required></input>
</div>

<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Try `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`.

Comment: An input should have a self-closing tag - e.g. <input /> or just <input> - Secondly, **why** do you want an input to be required if it is hidden from the user?

Comment: @moritzsalla no `visibility` is not what I need

Comment: How do you want to focus on something that doesn't exist?

Comment: @ckoala because I want to place this input in a specific pop up element that I do with `display: none / block` element

Comment: Could you append a new input dom element to the site when the validation error occurs? You could even use the [template tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp) to achieve this.

Comment: You can check a form’s / form field’s validation status via JavaScript – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation

Comment: @moritzsalla I want to make it visible and then focus. `visible` is not what I need because in this case It would still take up space on the page

Comment: What would trigger `display: block` in this case? As the answer stated below your question needs to be more descriptive on what you have tried and what you want to achieve, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by first calling [`checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#methods) of the Form.

If that reports that the Form is not valid, then gather the invalid elements using `.querySelectorAll(':invalid')` and then reveal those elements - or in this case, their parent divs.

Demo:

```js
function submitClick() {
  var theForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

  if (theForm.checkValidity()) {
    console.log("All elements are valid");
    return true; // Allow submit to proceed
  }

  var invalidItems = theForm.querySelectorAll(':invalid');

  for (var item of invalidItems) {
    console.log("Element " + item.name + " is not valid");
    item.parentNode.setAttribute("style", "display: block;")
  }
  return false; // Do not allow submit to proceed
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="alert('Form will be submitted')">

  <div style="display: none">
    Required field 1 (empty)<input name="v1" required value="" />
  </div>

  <div style="display: none">
    Required field 2 (Hello)<input name="v2" required value="Hello" />
  </div>

  <button type="submit" onclick="return submitClick();">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display property none to block in javascript code when the validation error occurred. Example Code

`

```
<form>

<div style="display: none">
    <input required></input>
</div>

<button type="submit">
</form>
<script>

    document.querySelector('input').style.display = 'block'

</script>
```

`

This code just an example. To give a solution to your code needs more descriptive.

Comment: I know how to display tjis element. I dont know hot to handle validation errror in inputs of this spesific div

Comment: Looks like What I need is $('#div_id')[0].checkValidity() but somewhy it throws me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].checkValidity is not a function`